# Перемещаемая форма со скрытыми границами

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы форму можно было перемещать мышкой за ее главное окно, даже если у нее скрыты границы?

p.s. + еще ко всему этому чтобы она `Resizable` была так же.

Comment: this.DragMove() - я курю, но правда я на wpf только пишу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно такое возможно. Один из вариантов - послать окну сообщение [`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645620(v=vs.85).aspx) на нажатие мыши, которое сигнализирует о нажатии левой клавиши мыши вне клиентской части окна, то есть на скрытых границах. Однако, перед этим действием необходимо снять "захват" курсора окном, иначе сообщение будет просто проигнорировано.

```
private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.Hold;
    Capture = false;
    Message msg = Message.Create(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,
        (IntPtr)HTCAPTION, IntPtr.Zero);
    DefWndProc(ref msg);
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

---

С ресайзингом придётся повозится дольше, тем более если его делать на этой же самой форме. Как вариант - сначала сделать ресайз только за правый нижний угол. Придётся переопределить оконную процедуру [`Form.WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc.aspx) и самому обработать сообщение [`WM_NCHITTEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618%28VS.85%29.aspx). Кстати, первую проблему можно тоже решить в этом месте. Более подробно смотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535826/resize-borderless-window-on-bottom-right-corner).